# Error with exception in Java using MessageDigest in JAASRealm

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, jaas

I have a function login() from JAASRealm:

```
@Override
public boolean login() throws LoginException {
   ...
}
```

I just want to use the MessageDigest object like this inside the login() function:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
```

But I take this error:

```
error: unreported exception NoSuchAlgorithmException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

So I create this function before login():

```
public String getPasswordDigest(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{

        try{
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte [] digestBytes = md.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            String digestString = new String(digestBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            return digestString;

        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            throw new  NoSuchAlgorithmException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in login() function I call:

```
String digestPassword = getPasswordDigest(saltedPassword);
```

But I get the same error.

I tried to do the following:

```
@Override
public boolean login() throws LoginException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
```

But I get this error:

```
login() in PlainLoginModule cannot implement login() in LoginModule
    public boolean login() throws LoginException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
                   ^
  overridden method does not throw NoSuchAlgorithmException
```

I don't know what to do in this case...